# How to use map for converting a list of decimals to hex in python

Tags: python, dictionary, hex

I have list like this: `a = ['12', ''34]`. Now I want to convert to a list of hexadecimals by using `map`, how to do that?

I mean, if I tried to convert it to a list of decimals, then I would do `map(int, a)`. Now what is its equivalent code to convert it in hex?

Comment: do you want to convert `'12'` to `'0xc'` or `18`?

Comment: @zhangxaochen I want `0xc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map(hex,map(int, a))
```

or perhaps

```
map(lambda x:int(x,16),a)
```

depending on what you are trying to do ...

Comment: Thanks, I needed the first one!

Answer (score 1):

or a list comprehension aside from @Joran's answer:

```
In [99]: [hex(int(i)) for i in a]
Out[99]: ['0xc', '0x22']
```